# could not convert string to float Python - Predictive Model

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a problem in my script in the following piece of a
prediction model:

```
x_treino = (x_treino.values.reshape(-1,1))
y_treino = (y_treino.values.reshape(-1,1))
modelo.fit(x_treino, y_treino)

modelo.fit(x_treino, y_treino)
```

returns this error:

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [34], in <cell line: 5>()
>       3 result = x_treino.replace('-', '')
>       4 result = y_treino.replace('-', '')
> ----> 5 modelo.fit(x_treino, y_treino) File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py:327, in
> BaseForest.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
>     325 if issparse(y):
>     326     raise ValueError("sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported.")
> --> 327 X, y = self._validate_data(
>     328     X, y, multi_output=True, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE
>     329 )
>     330 if sample_weight is not None:
>     331     sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X) File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:581, in
> BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately,
> **check_params)
>     579         y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
>     580     else:
> --> 581         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
>     582     out = X, y
>     584 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True): File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:964, in
> check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
> copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output,
> ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
>     961 if y is None:
>     962     raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
> --> 964 X = check_array(
>     965     X,
>     966     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
>     967     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
>     968     dtype=dtype,
>     969     order=order,
>     970     copy=copy,
>     971     force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
>     972     ensure_2d=ensure_2d,
>     973     allow_nd=allow_nd,
>     974     ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,
>     975     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
>     976     estimator=estimator,
>     977 )
>     979 y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric)
>     981 check_consistent_length(X, y) File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:746, in
> check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
> copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
> ensure_min_features, estimator)
>     744         array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
>     745     else:
> --> 746         array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
>     747 except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
>     748     raise ValueError(
>     749         "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
>     750     ) from complex_warning ValueError: could not convert string to float: '22-23'
```

Segue o código completo:

```
import pandas as pd
arquivo = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\prmatteo\OneDrive - COPERSUCAR S.A\Área de Trabalho\UNICA\Vendas - Açúcar.csv')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import re

arquivo.head()

# atribuindo valor numérico à última coluna 'red x white'
arquivo['TIPO DO PRODUTO'] = arquivo['TIPO DO PRODUTO'].replace('BRANCO', 0)

arquivo['TIPO DO PRODUTO'] = arquivo['TIPO DO PRODUTO'].replace('BRUTO', 1)

# separando as variáveis
y = arquivo['TIPO DO PRODUTO'] # armazena coluna 'TIPO DO PRODUTO' na variável y (variável alvo)
y = arquivo['TIPO DO PRODUTO'] # armazena coluna 'TIPO DO PRODUTO' na variável y (variável alvo)

x = arquivo.drop('TIPO DO PRODUTO', axis = 1) # armazena todo o restante na variável x (variáveis preditoras)

# conjunto de dados para treino e teste
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_treino, x_teste, y_treino, y_teste = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3) # test_size: quantos % p/ treino e p/ teste

# criação do modelo
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

modelo = ExtraTreesClassifier() # algoritmo que cria várias árvores de decisão

x_treino = (x_treino.values.reshape(-1,1))
y_treino = (y_treino.values.reshape(-1,1))
modelo.fit(x_treino, y_treino)

resultado = modelo.score(x_teste, y_teste)

print(f'Acurácia: {resultado}')

y_teste[205:210] # filtro de 5 amostras aleatóreas que o modelo não teve contato

x_teste[205:210] # filtro de 5 amostras aleatóreas que o modelo não teve contato

previsoes = modelo.predict(x_teste[205:210]) # criação de variável para checar se o modelo treinado acerta

print(previsoes) # modelo previu corretamente
```

how can i fix this?

**

Comment: Looks like it's trying to make `x_treino` to be a float array.  What is its `dtype` (and shape)?  From the error I suspect it is a string (or object) dtype, containing strings like '22-23'.  We can't suggest a fix since we don't have your data, or know what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: if you have a string variable you need to onehot encode it